# Character names changed while dubbing

Tags: animation, anime

Yesterday while I was watching **Scooby-Doo**, I deliberately changed the language settings from English to Hindi (popular Indian language) to have some fun. But throughout the telecast I noticed that except for the names of main characters like Daphne, Fred, Velma, Scooby, Shaggy, the names of supporting characters were changed to some very peculiar Indian names.

While this technique is not true in **Pokémon** where all the names are retained as they are in the English version of the anime. This might even be true for other cartoons, but I really do not remember much of the others as I do not watch all of them.

Why is the first technique followed for some, while others adapt the second? Is it only a matter of preference? Or is it convenience?

Comment: Is Pokémon a good example? The names were changed for Satoshi/Ash (for example) and almost all Pokémon (with the exception of Pikachu) between the Japanese and English versions.

Comment: Well... in *Pokemon*, [the English names are not the same as the original Japanese version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_characters#Characters) though (i.e. they were also changed while dubbing).

Comment: I agree. But most of them broadcasted here in India try to atleast retain the English ones. Hence my doubt. I am aware that Pokémon's names were changed for the English version of the same.

Comment: It's done a lot. Compulsory TV Tropes link - https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DubNameChange

Comment: The English dub for Crouching Tiger Hidden Dragon used different names to the English subtitles. Trying to watch with both was a highly confusing experience.